# Strange results with null in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, null

I ran the following code

```
public class MapTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(null, null);
        System.out.println(map.get(null));
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(null));
        System.out.println(map.containsValue(null));
    }
}
```

And it gave this output

```
null
true
true
```

However, when I remove the line `map.put(null, null)`, `map.get(null)` still returns null, but `map.containsKey(null)` & `map.containsValue(null)` return `false`. Now, if the value `null` is not associated with any key, how come it is possible that `map.get(null)` still returns `null`?

Comment: Because null is what `get` returns when it can't find the requested key in the map. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: yes try map.get("AAA") - you will get null

Comment: Also note that the eligibility of null as key or value in a Map is not defined in the interface but depends on the implementation

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for the `Map` interface states that [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) should return `null` for any key that does not have a mapping:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Note however that some `Map` implementations may not allow `null` keys, in which case `map.get(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. An example of this is the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: +1 The javadoc states the contract, which defines the behaviour seen

Answer (score 0):

If the map doesn't find the value in the map, then `get(object)` still returns `null`.

So for any arbitrary values you will get null as well.

Answer (score 0):

`map.get(null)` returns null because:

[Java Hash Map get Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)
>
> A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null. The containsKey operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.

This is possible:

```
map.put(null, null);
```

because:

[Java Hash Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an except of the get() source code of HashMap:

```
public V get(Object key) {
   if (key == null)
     return getForNullKey();
   ...
}
```

If the key passed is `null`, it gets that key and returns the value associated to it, else it returns null.

```
 private V getForNullKey() {
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         if (e.key == null)
            return e.value;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Strange behavior here. `Map`is a interface in java collection framework and `HashMap` is implementaion.

Simply map is a data structure allows to store key,value pair.

in here you are putting null as key and null as value. your `HashMap<String,Integer>` accept these value since `String` and `Integers` default value is `null`.

Then your are calling

> map.get(null) // argument is a key and return value assign to that key. So you are getting null.
>
> map.containsKey(null)// this method return true if particular key is there. In this case null is your key since return true
>   map.containsKey(null) // this method return true if there is null as value in your may. This case this is also true.

And the next time your are getting null since map is empty and Integers default value is null. and obviously other two method return false since map is empty.